# Multiple annotations found at this line: - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignBaseLine' in package 'android'

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Here is my .xml code it says "Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignBaseLine' in package 'android'". I don't know why this problem occurred. Someone help me.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.relativelayout.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseLine="@+id/button1"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseLine="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/texView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button1"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

[My Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DagN2.png)

Comment: Which type of layout you need? post here screen shot or sketch.

Comment: what is name of your xml file? are you getting that error in xml or in java class  file?

Comment: @sud it's "activity_main.xml". I got error when i'm trying to run the whole code.

Comment: have used that `layout_alignBaseLine` somewhere in your code? if not then post your code

Comment: @sud Only this .xml sir :) I used layout_alignbaseline

Comment: i did not get you... have you solved your problem?

Comment: now it run sir :) I don't know why i just restart the eclipse -_-

Answer (score 0):

there should be `layout_alignBaseline` not `layout_alignBaseLine` the second l letter should be lowercase

Comment: Sir. I tried to change it in lower case. But it says "there's error in your code". I got only warning sign in my .xml refer my screen shot i added it.